# Submitted an embedded link_to remote in a form remote causes form ajax to fire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the code below:

```
<script>
  $('#edit_profile_1').on('ajax:before', function(e) {
      alert('ajax:before');
  }).on('ajax:success', function(e) {
      // the form saved, alert the user via frontend visual changes
  });
</script>

<%= form_for @profile, remote: true do |f| %>
    <p>... Some stuff in form ...</p>
    <%= link_to some_path(@profile.some_fk_id), remote: true do %>
        Some Link
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit do %>
        Save
    <% end %>
    <p>... some footer stuff</p>
<% end %>
```

When submitting the form above, everything works as expected.  However, when clicking on the `<% link_to %>` in the above form, it also fires the form's ajax.

When a user clicks on the link in the form, the logic is to fire an access check on the backend controller and determines if a `javascript` modal partial loads or doesn't load (based on some business logic).  As it stands, the form saves (which is not what we want at when they click the link).

The question I have is how do you keep the form remote from firing, when I want just the links remote to fire?

Comment: what about a `preventDefault()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the approach I took was to check for the object type I'm dealing with in the javascript using similar code as below (you could take it a step further and check ID's for multiple forms -- or what we did in our actual code was to `extend` the javascript and pass option variables):

```
<script>
    $('#edit_profile_1').on('ajax:before', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('form')) {
            alert('do something with form');
        } else {
            alert('do something with a non-form');
        }
    }).on('ajax:success', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('form')) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    });
</script>
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way of handling this, but it's working the purposes for what we need.